# How to change the value of this field in all the records of this MySql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have the following situation.

In a **MySql** database I have a **posts** table. This table contains the following 2 fields: **post_modified** and **post_date**

For each record present in the **posts** table I need set the value of **post_modified** field with the value into the **post_date**

How can I do a query that do this work on all the table records?

Tnx

Comment: means the output should be with same data on every row?

Comment: You would have at least tried going through the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an easy one:

```
UPDATE posts SET post_modified = post_date;
```

Comment: @KM. I would have upvoted you too, three answers in 15 seconds :-)

Comment: It's funny to see people ask solution for this kind of simple thing as well and they call them self as programmer/developer :)

Answer (score 2):

This query should do the job :

```
UPDATE posts SET post_modified=post_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would just use an `update` without a condition to update all records:

```
update posts set post_modified = post_date
```

Depending on the settings in the database an update without a condition might not be allowed. Then you would add a dummy condition just to tell the database that you actually want to change every record:

```
update posts set post_modified = post_date where 1 = 1
```